# Patch service file

Tags: linux, systemd, services

I want to add `MY_SERVICE@SOME_SERVICE.service` to `OnFailure=` and make it persistent. For example, in `/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service`, I want to have the line `OnFailure=MY_SERVICE@apache2.service` in the `[Unit]` section.

This can be done with `systemctl edit`. However, if and when `apache2.service` contains an `OnFailure=` by default (for example, after updating to a newer version), it would be overriden with my changes. I want both the default `OnFailure=` and my own `OnFailure=` (for example, `OnFailure=default.service MY_SERVICE@apache2.service`).

How can I achieve this?

---

Default contents of `/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=The Apache HTTP Server
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=forking
Environment=APACHE_STARTED_BY_SYSTEMD=true
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful
PrivateTmp=true
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Contents of `/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service` after `systemctl edit` (added line 4)

```
[Unit]
Description=The Apache HTTP Server
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
OnFailure=MY_SERVICE@apache2.service

[Service]
Type=forking
Environment=APACHE_STARTED_BY_SYSTEMD=true
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful
PrivateTmp=true
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Contents of `/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service` after update with new default service for `apache2` in `OnFailure=` (modified line 4)

```
[Unit]
Description=The Apache HTTP Server
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
OnFailure=default.service MY_SERVICE@apache2.service

[Service]
Type=forking
Environment=APACHE_STARTED_BY_SYSTEMD=true
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful
PrivateTmp=true
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 3):

If you run [`systemctl edit apache2`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#edit%20UNIT%E2%80%A6), it should by default create an override snippet in `/etc/systemd/system/apache2.service.d`; it won’t edit the original in `/lib`. Add the following to your snippet:

```
[Unit]
OnFailure=MY_SERVICE@apache2.service
```

Because [`OnFailure`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#OnFailure=) is a list, and [isn’t reset in the snippet](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Examples), the value given above will be added to the entries specified in the original unit, it won’t replace them.